# AEAD not supported

Tags: wildfly

I'm using Wildlfy 21 and I configured the AEAD ciphers but a security scan still complains that AEAD is not supported.  I wonder if there is a way to tell Wildfly to only use the server side ciphers.  Or am I missing another configuration somewhere.  Here's the relevant part of my standalone.xml:

```
            <server name="default-server">
                <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
                <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enabled-cipher-suites="ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384,ECDHE\
-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384,ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305,ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305,ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256,ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256,ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SH\
A384,ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384,ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256,ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256" enabled-protocols="TLSv1.2" enable-http2="false"/>
                <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                    <http-invoker security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
                </host>
            </server>
```

I would really appreciate any help you could give me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is my cipher suites are too broad.  I changed them to just those that are AEADs.  I hope this will satisfy the scan.